# Como resolver esta situação na parte de layout?

Tags: css, layout, webdesign, photoshop

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como, através das ferramentas do Photoshop CS5(CS6) eu posso fazer ou o branco ou o preto chegar na cor apontada pelo código hexadecimal que também é o da imagem colorida maior.

Eu tentei chegar a este resultado usando a ferramenta de Matiz/Saturação mas sem sucesso visto que não entendo nada de design e misturas de cores e iluminação e essas coisas ai. rsrsrs

Estou usando estas ferramentas? http://puu.sh/aHjZR/5395b5097e.png

Não é uma imagem sólida, ela tem efeitos, então teria que ser coisa pro lado Matiz/Saturação: http://puu.sh/aHkQQ/37fde2c258.png

Ficarei muito agradecido e posso até dar uma recompensa a quem posso me ajudar.

Comment: Não é uma imagem sólida, ela tem efeitos, então teria que ser coisa pro lado Matiz/Saturação: http://puu.sh/aHkQQ/37fde2c258.png

Comment: Você quer fazer um degradê desde o preto até o rosa?

Answer (score 0):

What about paint bucket ? (o balde) xd

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é uma imagem sólida, ela tem efeitos, então teria que ser coisa pro lado Matiz/Saturação: http://puu.sh/aHkQQ/37fde2c258.png

Comment: ah, now i get your feel xd, boa sorte ai mano xD

Comment: @Andrey , nunca respondeste a uma pergunta com uma sugestão ? se ele não tivesse editado a pergunta a informar que não era aquela imagem, era uma resposta direta..

Answer (score 0):

Por lógica se a cor em hexadecimal da imagem é a mesma do fundo e você quer aplicar 
essa cor ao preto e ao branco, ela ficará na mesma cor do fundo você pode utilizar a ferramenta de medição do Photoshop para identificar a cor e o balde ou um *brush* para pintar.

[image: Visão geral do painel de ferramentas]

Comment: Não é uma imagem sólida, ela tem efeitos, então teria que ser coisa pro lado Matiz/Saturação: http://puu.sh/aHkQQ/37fde2c258.png

Answer (score 0):

Então coloca lá na ferramenta que você ta usando

Hue/Matriz           : 346
Saturation/Saturação : 31
Value/Luminosidade   : 79

Para você descobrir Converta o exa em Rgb e o Rgb Em HSV pronto
fora esses links deve ter programas ou outros sites mas ai fica a sua escolha.

[Converter Para RGB](http://www.csgnetwork.com/csgcolorsel4.html)

[Converter Rgb Para Hsv](http://www.csgnetwork.com/csgcolorsel4.html)